# How can I get a list of users of a certain LDAP group with curl command?

Tags: ldap

I need to get some ldap user list with curl command.

In order to get locked users, I used

```
curl 'ldaps://LDAP_SERVER/ou=users,dc=my,dc=example,dc=com?memberOf?sub?(pwdaccountlockedtime=*)'
```

How can I get the list of users who are under 'admins' group?

`cn=admins,ou=groups,dc=my,dc=practice,dc=com`